# MySQL now() in database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to put the time of a post into my database table but i can't get it to work. maybe someone here can explain what i'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['upload_message'])) {
    $message_title = $_POST['message_title'];
    $message_content = $_POST['message_content'];
}

$table_name = "posts";
$add_query = "INSERT INTO $table_name (name, content, date) VALUES ('$message_title', '$message_content', 'SELECT NOW()')";

if (mysql_query($add_query)) { //executes query and error check
    echo "het artikel staat in de database";
}
else { //error message
    echo "fout bij het toevoegen" . "<br />" . mysql_error();
}

?>
```

and this is a screen shot of my db table : http://gyazo.com/17019f143eab6e5818752c33824bde29

When I run mysql_error is get the following message :

> Incorrect datetime value: 'SELECT NOW()' for column 'date' at row 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to `SELECT NOW()`, just `NOW()`

```
$add_query = "INSERT INTO $table_name (name, content, date) 
    VALUES ('$message_title', '$message_content', NOW())";
```

You should use prepared statements with binded parameters using `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

NOW() is a mysql function, you don't have to "select it" just call it.

Replace the "SELECT NOW()" for just "NOW()".

```
INSERT INTO $table_name (name, content, date) VALUES ('$message_title', '$message_content', 'NOW()')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
INSERT INTO $table_name (name, content, date) VALUES ('$message_title', '$message_content', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score -1):

Mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

Use PDO or Mysqli !

And secure your code, we can do injection sql.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.